# Custom Directive for Table with different object properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Suppose I would like to write a reusable + universal directive that will be used throughout my whole project. This directive will be displaying a table, as follows:

```
angular
    .module('demo')
    .directive('indexTable', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<tr ng-repeat=" component in components>' +
                        '<td ng-repeat="obj in component">' +
                          '{{obj}}' + 
                        '</td>' + 
                       '</tr>',
            scope: {
                 components: '=',
            },
            link: function (scope, attrs) {
            }
        }
    });
```

Supposing in my controller I have two different arrays with each two sets of different objects with different properties:

```
//some mockup data
angular.module('demo')
   .controller('demoCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    //array 1
    $scope.userArray = [
      {Id:1 , Name: 'Chuck Norris', Age:'21'},
      {Id:2 , Name: 'George Bush' , Age: '42'}
    ];
    //array 2 
    $scope.itemArray = [
      {Id:1, ProductNo: '001', BasePrice: 20.20, Value: 50.50} 
      {Id:2, ProductNo: '002', BasePrice: 20.20, Value: 50.50} 
    ];
}]);
```

So basically the question is:  How do I select (in controller) what are the properties to be displayed in the table?

Question In-Depth : Now I have two different arrays with each of their own properties. How I would use it in my HTML will be

`<div index-table components="userArray"></div>`

Take the `itemArray` for example. Each object will have 4 properties, namely `Id`, `ProductNo`, etc. But in my table, I would only want to display 2 of which, say only `ProductNo` and `BasePrice`. How do I discard the other two properties that I do not want? As you can see from my partial template there, I am using double `ng-repeats`.

Things I have considered / tried so far: Tried Mapping objects to array, but I believe `ng-repeat` is far more intelligent. Do I need to add in more scope attributes? How do I write my link function? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an attribute defining the property names that will populate each column. E.g.:

```
<table index-table
    components="itemArray"
    columns="ProductNo,BasePrice"
></table>
```

Your directive has to be slightly modified:

```
app.directive('indexTable', function() {
    function parseProps(str) {
        // implement parse logic, return an array of strings - the property names
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template:
            '<tr ng-repeat="component in components">' +
                '<td ng-repeat="name in props">' +
                    '{{ component[name] }}' + 
                '</td>' + 
            '</tr>',
        scope: {
            components: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.props = parseProps(attrs.columns);
        }
    };
});
```

You can see a sample implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/y54x0hcd/

This has a lot of rough edges (e.g.: column titles?); maybe it would be better to use a grid library.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment! and thanks for the regex! Its okay for the column titles. I added another `scope` component for it. I chose not use the grid library though. This serves what I want and I reduced the code based by at least 30% with this directive :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass in to your directive the properties you wish to display? Then your ng-repeat would look something like this:

```
                    '<td ng-repeat="obj in component">'
                      '{{obj[passedInDisplayKey]}}'
                    '</td>'
```